# SLF4J: log to console and file at the same time

Tags: java, maven, logging, intellij-idea, slf4j

There are various examples there and some which I do not understand very well (and did not work for me so far).
Would someone please give a clear functional **example** of how to configure and use both console and file logging (at the same time).

I would like to continue with `SLF4J`, but any other might do as well. Based on `SLF4J`, it could be any of `Simple` or `Log4j`; maybe use `logback-classic`?

Included files:

- simpleLogger.properties
- logback.xml?
- other?
- no config files at all?

At the moment I'm using `Simple` and I can either log to `console` or to a `file`, using `simpleLogger.properties`, but not both; I guess `Simple` might have its limitations.

I'm new to the logger world. Please be simplistic.

Comment: please go through this tutorial https://www.mkyong.com/logging/logback-xml-example/. it explains everything to meet your requirement.

Comment: After a while, I quit `SLF4J simple` and went to `logback`, this solved my issue to print on both `console` and `file`